# Unexpected distortion in flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a three even columns using flexbox. In CodePen it looks more clear: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/KKVwvoQ

Here is the code:

```css
.rowIdeas {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.columnIdeas {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.maxSize {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- about ideas section start -->

<div class="rowIdeas">
  <div class="columnIdeas iransansdnlight">
    <div>
      <img class="maxSize" src="https://langfox.ir/vc/philosophy.svg">
      <h2>Item one</h2>
      <p>Flex items do not need to be block level unless the content they contain requires it. Also, you've prefixed all of the display properties, but didn't prefix any of the other Flexbox properties (which have different names in the other drafts).</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="idea columnIdeas iransansdnlight">
    <div>
      <img class="maxSize" src="https://langfox.ir/vc/idea.svg">
      <h2>item two</h2>
      <p>Flex items do not need to be block level unless the content they contain requires it. Also, you've prefixed all of the display properties, but didn't prefix any of the other Flexbox properties (which have different names in the other drafts).
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columnIdeas iransansdnlight">
    <div>
      <img class="maxSize" src="https://langfox.ir/vc/results.svg">
      <h2>item three</h2>
      <p>Flex items do not need to be block level unless the content they contain requires it. Also, you've prefixed all of the display properties, but didn't prefix any of the other Flexbox properties (which have different names in the other drafts).</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--  about ideas section ends -->
```

The code works fine here and in CodePen, **but when I put the same code in my landing page, I see this**:

[image]

As you see the first one goes a bit upper than others.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: If you cannot recreate the issue here, nobody can help you. Maybe you can add a link to your landing page where people can see the problem.

Comment: The code you throw works both on codepen and on my own computer. Is everything okay ?

Comment: The code works fine here and in codepen But when I put the same code in my landing page I see the distortion...

Comment: I think it has to do with the size of the images. Just to test, try adding a `max-width: 100px` to see if that solves it. Then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the svg images are differnt proportions. So the one on the left is actually *shorter*, so the title doesn't drop as low as the others. You'll have to either give them a specific height, remake it so they're all the same height, or otherwise account for the varying sizes.

Comment: You're a genius man!!! ... giving  `height: 200px; ` fixed them all.... But wait why I get a good result here and on codepen?!

Comment: I think it has to do with the width of the viewport in combination with your `max-height` selector.